# .htaccess rewrite rule from one page to another not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have problem with .htaccess for one page in my website.

I need to rewrite this page

```
https://www.lepremier.cz/Product/Index?categoryID=61
```

to this

```
https://www.lepremier.cz/33-loake
```

I tried this two rules

```
RewriteRule ^/Product/Index?categoryID=61$ http://www.lepremier.cz/23-boty-loake [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 /Product/Index?categoryID=61(.*) /33-loake/$1
```

but not working.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request parameters (the stuff following the `?` in the URI is *not* part of the request URL. That means you cannot match it in a `RewriteRule`. You have to use a `RewriteCond` for this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "categoryID=61"
RewriteRule ^/Product/Index$ http://www.lepremier.cz/23-boty-loake [R=301,L]
```

This is all documented, it certainly makes sense if you start reading the documentation of the tools you want to use: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

---

And a general note, since you will stumble over this:

The pattern you yourself chose will *not* work in `.htaccess` style files, since it starts with a leading slash (`/`) which will *never* match. Matching in `.htaccess` style files works on *relative paths* for obvious reasons.

Nevertheless I did not modify that, since you should always prefer to place such rules inside your http servers host configuration anyway. In there your chosen syntax with the leading slash *will* work as expected. `.htaccess` style files are notorioously error prone, hard to debug and they *really* slow the http server down for nothing. They are only offered as a last option for situations where people do *not* have access to the host configuration. So for example when using a cheap shared hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually that's not working. Its a specific place in .htaccess file where should i put this code?

Comment: And "that's not working" means what exactly? Redirecting to something wrong? Not redirecting at all? Is there an entry in the error log file? Do you get an error in your client? Does the universe implode?

Comment: I just check on one of my systems, the above works as predicted. However keep in mind that I pointed out that this will _not_ work unmodified in `.htaccess` style files, only in the real http servers host configuration. Did you read and understand that? If you still want to use some `.htaccess` style file, then you have to remove that leading slash in the `RewriteRule`'s pattern.

Comment: So for a `.htaccess` style file you need to use that pattern instead: `^Product/Index$`. Note the _removed_ leading slash.